# How to seed boolean values into rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I seed a rails app boolean column given data of the form `"t", "f", "f", "t"` etc etc

I suspect if I seed these strings to a boolean column I will receive an error

For context, the `"t", "f", "f", "t"` format is how boolean data appears when extracted as a CSV from the postgresql database

For further context, the current seed file looks as such

```rb
csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('lib', 'seeds', 'bands.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text.scrub, headers: true)
csv.each do |row|
  t = Band.new
  t.band_name = row['band_name']
  t.category_1 = row['category_1']
  t.category_2 = row['category_2']
  t.category_3 = row['category_3']
  t.category_4 = row['category_4']
  t.link = row['link']
  t.time = Time.zone.parse(row['time'])
  t.image = row['image']
  t.available = row['available'] # This is the boolean column
  t.save
  puts "#{t.band} saved"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the string received something like this

```
t.available = row['available'] == 't'
```

This will assign `t.available` with boolean `true` else `false`

If you want to check for both values and keep it `nil` in case the value is not provided you can use

```
t.available = if row['available'] == 't' 
                true
              elsif row['available'] == 'f'
                false
              end
```

Comment: Could also use one of the following to achieve the latter: `row['available']&.== 't' ` or `row['available'].try(:==, 't')`. _Think_ I'd lean towards your approach for clarity, though the option's there :) +1 btw